# Why can't I create an ECS Task Definition with Inference Accelerators attached?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I would like to experiment with attaching Inference Accelerators to an ECS task.
I created the following Cloudformation template:

```
{
    "Resources": {
        "Task": {
          "Type" : "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
          "Properties" : {
              "ContainerDefinitions" : [
                  {
                      "Name": "TestAccelerated",
                      "Image": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/myimage",
                      "Essential": true,
                      "ResourceRequirements": [{
                          "Type": "InferenceAccelerator",
                          "Value": "eia-device-1"
                      }]
                  }
              ],
              "Cpu" : "256",
              "ExecutionRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
              "Family" : "TestService",
              "InferenceAccelerators" : [ {
                "DeviceName": "eia-device-1",
                "DeviceType": "eia1.medium"
              } ],
              "Memory" : "512",
              "NetworkMode" : "awsvpc",
              "RequiresCompatibilities" : [ "FARGATE" ],
              "TaskRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to create the stack, cloudformation fails with the following error:

```
Invalid request provided: Create TaskDefinition: Unsupported field 'inferenceAccelerators'
```

However there are two things that seem strange to me:

- The field I used has an uppercase I, while the error mentions it with lowercase i
- The field InferenceAccelerators is supposedly a supported field according to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html)

Is there something wrong that I'm doing, is this a bug, or for some reason Inference Accelerators are really not supported in Task Definitions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you are using `FARGATE` and Fargate **does not support GPUs**. But the support is already on the AWS roadmap:

- [AWS Fargate GPU Support: When is GPU support coming to fargate?](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/88)

You can try redefine your task definition and ecs service for EC2 launch type, instead of Fargate.

**Update**

Amazon Elastic Inference is [only for EC2-type ECS tasks](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/09/amazon-elastic-inference-now-available-in-amazon-ecs-tasks/):

> This feature is supported when using Linux containers and tasks that use the **EC2 launch type**.

Comment: I replaced `Fargate` with `ECS` in the `RequiresCompatibilities` field, but get exactly the same error. 

Also, I understand that GPUs are not supported on Fargate yet, but I was under the impression that IAs actually [are network attached devices](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/elastic-inference/faqs/), so one would expect them to work on Fargate instances.

Comment: @feralgeometry They are only for EC2-type tasks, not fargate. I added this to answer.